# How would I say in words, the description of this set in mathematics notation?

Tags: general-topology

$$S^{n-1}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\|x\|=1\}$$

Would it be right to say, $S$ is the set of all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ such that the norm of the vectors, by whichever specified notion of distance, is equal to one?

Why is $S^{n-1}$ used instead of $S^n$? If it is the set of all vectors of norm one in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then shouldn't it also have the same dimensions as $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Like, my problem is, I don't see how I can approach the question I'm working on without being able to visualise such a set in space.

Comment: The set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \|x\|=1\}$ would usually be named *the unit $(n-1)$-sphere*, or if there was any ambiguity about norms, *the unit $(n-1)$-sphere for the norm $\|\;\|$*.

Comment: $S^0$ is the two-point set $\{-1,1\}$ inside $\mathbb{R}$. Since it consist of isolated points, it is considered 0-dimensional (it is a 0-dimensional mainfold). Then $S^1$ is the unit circle inside $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since it is a smooth curve embedded in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ in a nice way, the circle $S^1$ is 1-dimensional. And $S^2$ is the sphere (i.e. the infinitely thin spherical shell, not the solid ball) inside $\mathbb{R}^3$. Since $S^2$ is a nice smooth surface, its dimension is 2. And so on.

Answer (score 4):

For your first question, it is written in a strange way. For instance, there is no use for "by whichever specified notion of distance". The norm has already been specified. You could have only said:

"...is the set of the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which have norm equal to $1$"

Now, for your second question,

$S^{n}$ has an intrinsic nature. It can bee seen in many different topological ways, aside from being an embedded manifold inside $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. It is the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the quotient of the disk by identifying the boundary, the smash product of $S^1 $ $n$ times etc. The invariant thing is: it is always a $n$-manifold. It is therefore more natural to assign the number $n$ in the notation.

Answer (score 3):

Say instead,

> $S^{n-1}$ is the set of all vectors in $\mathbb R^{n}$ such that the norm of the vectors, by whichever specified notion of distance, is equal to one.

(notice the subtle differences?) We call it $S^{n-1}$ because each point therein is contained in an open set which "looks like" (is homeomorphic to, if you are familiar) an open set in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$. In other words, $S^{n-1}$ has $n-1$ dimensions locally, not $n$. Of course, you could replace $n$ with $n+1$, and you would have a perfectly good definition of $S^n$ in terms of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

Your argument that as a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, the sphere ought to have dimension $n$ breaks down when we consider $$\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n:x_1=0\}.$$ This set is the same topologically as $\mathbb R^{n-1}$, so it has $n-1$ dimensions. For $S^{n-1}$, we are doing something similar.

Manifold families with an $n$ attached ($\mathbb T^n,\mathbb{RP^n},\mathbb{R}^n$,S^n etc...) are usually locally $n$ dimensional, so this index helps us understand the structure of the manifold.

Visualizing $S^{n}$ is not too hard when $n=1$ or $n=2$. These are just the circle and sphere sitting inside $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$ respectively. In higher dimensions, it is harder to visualize, so the topologist has to rely on theorems and poorly drawn pictures to do his work.

Answer (score 3):

$S^{n-1}$ the surface of the unit hyper-sphere of the $n$-dimension real (Cartesian-coordinate) space.

The index is $n-1$ because it is a surface; thus having one less dimension than the space, $\Bbb R^n$ , in which that hyper-sphere resides.

Comment: Ok, say Im looking at $\Bbb{R}$, then the set of vectors with norm one can be spanned with (0,1), so $S$ is 1 dimensional. Moving on, looking at $\Bbb{R}^2$, then the set of vectors with norm one can be spanned with (1,0), (0,1), so like $\Bbb{R}^2$, S is 2 dimensional. So on and so forth, i would think that It should be ${S}^n$ rather than ${S}^{n-1}$.

Comment: @MrMachine $S^{n-1}$ is not a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ so you can not assign to it linear dimension. The exponent in "$S^{n-1}$" refers to another kind of dimension: Points have dimension $0$, curves have dimension $1$, surfaces have dimension $2$, and so on... For the general definition have a look at what an $n$-manifold is. It locally looks like $\mathbb{R^n}$. For example $S^1$ which is a circle, locally looks like $\mathbb{R}$, hence the exponent.

Answer (score 2):

The set you gave is the set of all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with norm one. *Not* the set of all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ with norm 1.

Why do we call this set $S^{n-1}$? Well, if you study topology/manifolds, you'll see that $S^{n-1}$ is an $n-1$ dimensional manifold. Put more simply, while $S^{n-1}$ is a subset of $n$ dimensional real space, it locally looks like it has $n-1$ dimensions. So we label it like that.

It might be helpful to think of the case of $n=2$. Then $\mathbb{R}^n$ is just the plane, and $S^{n-1}$ is the set of all points of the plane with norm 1: the unit circle. The circle is one-dimensional (it's locally homeomorphic to a line segment, and any point on it can be described by just a single coordinate $\theta$). Similarly, $S^2$ is just the surface of the unit sphere in three dimensional space.

Comment: Replying to your case of n=2,Ok, say Im looking at $\Bbb{R}$, then the set of vectors with norm one can be spanned with (0,1), so $S$ is 1 dimensional. Moving on, looking at $\Bbb{R}^2$, then the set of vectors with norm one can be spanned with (1,0), (0,1), so like $\Bbb{R}^2$, S is 2 dimensional. So on and so forth, i would think that It should be ${S}^n$ rather than ${S}^{n-1}$.

Comment: @MrMachine $S$ is not a vector space. It's a manifold. Dimension is defined differently for the two examples.

Comment: @MrMachine You can't really say $S$ is a two-dimensional vector space, since it's clearly not a vector space to begin with.

Comment: @MrMachine We mean that $S^2$ is two-dimensional in the same way we'd say the surface of the earth is two-dimensional. We know it lives in three dimensional space, but it still looks pretty flat.